# C - Glib GINT_TO_POINTER portability

Tags: c, performance, portability, glib

I'm dealing with large numbers coming from the hash table. I'm wondering what would be a good way of adding them to a constant (100) taking into account portability. Glib's documentation  highlights that using GINT_TO_POINTER is not portable in any way. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
gpointer v, old_key;
gint value; // ?

if(g_hash_table_lookup_extended(table, key, &old_key, &v)){
    value = GPOINTER_TO_INT(v); // ?
    value = value + 100;
}
g_hash_table_replace(table, g_strdup(key), GINT_TO_POINTER(value)); // ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing an integer inside a pointer, have the pointer point to an integer:

```
gpointer v, old_key;
int *int_v;
if(g_hash_table_lookup_extended(table, key, &old_key, &v)){
    int_v = (int *)v;
    int new_value = *int_v + 100;
    int_v = g_malloc(sizeof(int));
    *int_v = new_value;
}
g_hash_table_replace(table, g_strdup(key), int_v);
```

For a new value, use `g_malloc`:

```
// ...
int *value = g_malloc(sizeof(int));
// ...
g_hash_table_insert(table, key, value);
```

To ensure keys and values are destroyed properly, pass destructor functions like `g_free` to `g_hash_table_new_full`.

Comment: This is technically correct, but since using `GINT_TO_POINTER` _is_ portable for storing 32-bit integers in pointers, it is unnecessary and inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with gnome library, but from [GNOME Documentation Library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html#glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.details):

> **YOU MAY NOT STORE POINTERS IN
>   INTEGERS.** THIS IS NOT PORTABLE IN ANY
>   WAY SHAPE OR FORM. **These macros ONLY
>   allow storing integers in pointers,
>   and only preserve 32 bits of the
>   integer;** values outside the range of a
>   32-bit integer will be mangled.

The only thing not portable is to store pointers in integers. If you just:

- Store integers in pointers. (not pointers in integer).
- The integer does not not exceed 32 bits.

It shall be okay.